# How can I set .bash_profile environment variable in Dockerfile?

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

I want to set bash environment variable in Dockerfile.
How I can do it?

Host: OS X 10.11.4
Guest: ubuntu:latest

Dockerfile:

```
RUN mkdir ~/gopath_dir
RUN apt-get install ubuntu-make
RUN umake go

# I want to set $GOPATH to ~/gopath_dir
```

Comment: You know there are official golang images? https://hub.docker.com/_/golang/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare a environment variable with the ENV statement

```
ENV foo=hello
```

Comment: Well that's how you do it, so you need to explain what happens and what you want to happen.